# SQL SUM, Group by and Having query

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, sum, having

I have a pretty standard query that will get me a list of products that have stock above 0.

This works fine, however I now need to ADD the SUM of all negative numbers for BranchID 31 for the given SKU.

```
SELECT * FROM Products WHERE
PrimaryPLU IN 
(select SKU FROM Stock 
WHERE BranchID IN (2,12,1,11,0,96,32,13,14,15) 
AND ApplicationID = @site 
GROUP BY SKU HAVING(SUM(Stock)) > 0))
```

SO BranchID 31 can have positive and negative numbers, however I just need to get the sum of the negative ones for the SKU, this then needs to be added to the check to see if it's over 0.

Not a clue where to start, was hoping for support from a SQL master!

Thanks in advance!

Dave

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM Products WHERE
PrimaryPLU IN 
(select SKU FROM Stock 
WHERE BranchID IN (2,12,1,11,0,96,31,32,13,14,15) 
AND ApplicationID = @site 
GROUP BY SKU HAVING(SUM(CASE WHEN Stock < 0 AND BranchID = 31 
              THEN Stock ELSE 0 END)) > 0))
```

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't check BranchID 31, I think I need something like:

SELECT * FROM Products WHERE PrimaryPLU IN
(2,12,1,11,0,96,32,13,14,15) 
AND ApplicationID = @site
GROUP BY SKU HAVING(SUM(Stock))+(SELECT SUM(stock) FROM Stock WHERE BranchID = 31 AND Stock < 0 AND SKU = ????) > 0))

Comment: I changed the code a bit, maybe you can use BranchID 31 too in your where, but for this only use the positive values

Answer (score 0):

Take the sum of absolute value of the negative numbers (stock) to see if they are non-zero.